# Karma requirejs lodash

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-requirejs

I am using `karma`, `jasmine`, `requirejs` and `lodash`. When I started project I got error like this:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR                                                    
  Error: Module name "../lodash.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded                                          
  at <project_path>/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:143
```

I was not able to google out solution. Only what I found is [this closed github issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/707) which didnt helped me.

Answer (score 0):

After several try-fail-modifies I found that once I downgraded `lodash ~4` to `lodash ~3` the error disapeared. This is sufficient solution for me.